# Group of Integer Valued Functions on Interior of Unit Circle

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, connectedness

This is from Higson's Analytic K-Homology.

> Let $X$ be a non-empty and compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. An **index function** for $X$ is an integer-valued function on the set of bounded components of the complement of $X$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

> Brown-Douglas-Fillmore Theorem: If $X$ is any non-empty and compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ then the semigroup Ext $(X)$ is a group. The map which associates to $[T] \in \operatorname{Ext}(X)$ the index function of $T$ is an isomorphism from Ext $(X)$ to the group of all index functions for $X$.

Using BDF theorem, I wish to prove
$\text { Index : } \operatorname{Ext}\left(\mathrm{S}^1\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
$ is an isomorphism.

In the above definition of index function, putting $X=S^1$. So the interior ${S^1}^\circ$ is the only bounded component. How do I prove the group of integer valued functions on ${S^1}^\circ$ is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of index function says that a bounded component is mapped to a single integer. Since the set of bounded components is $\{{S^1}^\circ\}$, we have $\mathbb{Z}$-many choices to map ${S^1}^\circ$ to.